# r: pmatch isn't working for big dataframe

Tags: r, map-matching

I have two **dataframes**, first one (`dt`) contains of all `chr` and second one (`TargetWord`) is a dictionary contains `chr` as well. I have used `pmatch` to search in `dt` which words are available in the `TargetWord` and returning the position from `TargetWord`. It is working fine when dataframes are small. **But problem starts when the dataframes are huge, it is returning the word position for only the first column, rest of the columns are becoming NA**.

```
## Data Table
word_1 <- c("conflict","", "resolved", "", "", "")
word_2 <- c("", "one", "tricky", "one", "", "one")
word_3 <- c("thanks","", "", "comments", "par","")
word_4 <- c("thanks","", "", "comments", "par","")
word_5 <- c("", "one", "tricky", "one", "", "one")
dt <- data.frame(word_1, word_2, word_3,word_4, word_5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Targeted Words
TargetWord <- data.frame(cbind(c("conflict", "thanks", "tricky", "one", "two", "three")))

## convert into matrix (needed)
dt <- as.matrix(dt)
TargetWord <- as.matrix(TargetWord)

result <- `dim<-`(pmatch(dt, TargetWord, duplicates.ok=TRUE), dim(dt))
print(result)
```

Returning result,

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   NA    2    2   NA
[2,]   NA    4   NA   NA    4
[3,]   NA    3   NA   NA    3
[4,]   NA    4   NA   NA    4
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA    4   NA   NA    4
```

Now after reading two `.csv` as bellow, **result is just for the first column where I want it for all columns like above result**. Bellow, dt1 = 79*50 dataframe, and word_dict 13901*1 dataframe.

```
#################### on big data #####################################
dt1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/Wonderland/Downloads/string_feature.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
word_dict <- read.csv("C:/Users/Wonderland/Downloads/word_dict.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt1 <- as.matrix(dt1)
word_dict <- as.matrix(word_dict)

result <- `dim<-`(pmatch(dt1, word_dict, duplicates.ok=TRUE), dim(dt1))
print(result)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? An unexpected result? If so, how it differs from the  expected result? How do you think anybody could help?

Comment: thanks nicola. I am actually not getting error, what is the unexpected result means, same code when I am running on my actual data, the outcome is only for one column (first column). I want to find the word position from the word dictionary all over the dataframe

Comment: A good question should provide a reproducible example and a clear description of the problem. You aren't providing neither. What `the outcome is only for one column` is supposed to mean? The other columns are all `NA`s? Or there aren't other columns? Did you try to subset your data, to see if the issue persists? Why don't you share some data? Or at least some info on them (for instance the output of `str` and similar on each object involved), if they are too big.

Comment: sorry, new in stackoverflow. you see my result for the small dataframe, the word position is coming for each of the column. and for big dataframe it is coming for only the `first column`, `rest of the column is returning NA`

Comment: if you do not mind, how can I upload such big dataframe here in stackoverflow?

Comment: How do you know if the result is wrong? What `pmatch(dt1[,2], word_dict, duplicates.ok=TRUE)` produces?

Comment: It is returning all `NA`, I know the result is wrong, because some words from the `word_dict` are present in the `dt1`

Comment: what I am actually looking for,search in the `dt1` for all row and all columns, if any word is present in the `word_dict`, returning the word position replacing the word.

Comment: Are you sure? `R` is telling the contrary and it is usually right. Find manually some element of the second column of `dt1` (i.e. `dt1[,2]`) that appears in `word_dict`.

Comment: thanks again for your time. I am trying it for long, strange is beside first column, rest of all are becoming `NA`, that should not happened. whatever, I will try my best.

Answer (score 0):

Try with apply:

```
apply(dt,2,function(x) pmatch(x,TargetWord,duplicates.ok = T))
```

As you can see, the result is the same but it probably works with huge dataframe

```
     word_1 word_2 word_3 word_4 word_5
[1,]      1     NA      2      2     NA
[2,]     NA      4     NA     NA      4
[3,]     NA      3     NA     NA      3
[4,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
[5,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
[6,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

I tried with:

```
word_1 <- rep(c("conflict","", "resolved", "", "", ""),1000)
word_2 <- rep(c("", "one", "tricky", "one", "", "one"),1000)
word_3 <- rep(c("thanks","", "", "comments", "par",""),1000)
word_4 <- rep(c("thanks","", "", "comments", "par",""),1000)
word_5 <- rep(c("", "one", "tricky", "one", "", "one"),1000)
```

with all the same code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`pmatch` currently works olny for sizes up to [100](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d29fd8b7f3221aaef97f0980108a230623274442/src/main/unique.c#L1603).

```
pmatch(rep("a", 100), rep("a", 100))
#  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
# [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
# [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
# [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
# [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
# [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

pmatch(rep("a", 101), rep("a", 101))
#  [1]  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [26] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [51] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#[101] NA
```