# Output of pmatch changes with vector length

Tags: r

I am trying to use `pmatch` in base `R`.  The following example appears to work as expected:

```
treat1   <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
              2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
              4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5,
              5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7,
              7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8,
              8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,10,
             10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,
             11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,
             13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,
             14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,
             16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,
             17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18)

control1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
              2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,
              4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6,
              6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8,
              8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,10,
             10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,
             12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,
             13,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,
             15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,
             17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18)

pmatch(control1, treat1)
#[1]   1   2   3   4   5   8   9  10  11  12
#     13  14  15  16  17  18  21  22  23  24
#     25  26  27  28  29  30  31  34  35  36
#     37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  47  48
#     49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  60
#     61  62  63  64  65  67  68  69  70  71
#     73  74  75  76  77  78  80  81  82  83
#     84  86  87  88  89  90  91  93  94  95
#     96  97  99 100 101 102 103 104 106 107
#    108 109 110 112 113 114 115 116 117
```

However, the following example does not work as I expected.  The only difference between the example above and the one below is the presence of a few additional `elements` of value `19` at the end of the `vectors` below.  The `output` below contains numerous `NA's` and only seems to include the `position` in `treat2` of the first `element` of a given `value` in `control2`.  I have tried including some of the `options` for `pmatch` in the `documentation` but cannot get output similar to that shown above.

There are several similar questions on `Stack Overflow`, such as the following, but I have not found a solution to my issue:

[Properties of pmatch function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219724/properties-of-pmatch-function)

```
treat2   <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
              2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
              4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5,
              5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7,
              7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8,
              8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,10,
             10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,
             11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,
             13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,
             14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,
             16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,
             17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,
             19,19,19,19,19)

control2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
              2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,
              4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6,
              6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8,
              8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,10,
             10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,
             12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,
             13,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,
             15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,
             17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,
             19,19,19,19)

pmatch(control2, treat2)
#[1]   1  NA  NA  NA  NA   8  NA  NA  NA  NA
#     NA  14  NA  NA  NA  NA  21  NA  NA  NA
#     NA  NA  27  NA  NA  NA  NA  34  NA  NA
#     NA  NA  NA  40  NA  NA  NA  NA  47  NA
#     NA  NA  NA  NA  53  NA  NA  NA  NA  60
#     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  67  NA  NA  NA  NA
#     73  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  80  NA  NA  NA
#     NA  86  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  93  NA  NA
#     NA  NA  99  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 106  NA
#     NA  NA  NA 112  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 119
#     NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Have a look at [r: pmatch isn't working for big dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654375) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your `treat` and `control` are always numbers, I think it might be easier (and faster) to just rewrite that function using `Rcpp`. Consider something like this

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector cpmatch(NumericVector x, NumericVector table) {
  int n = x.size(), m = table.size();
  NumericVector out(n, NA_REAL), y = clone(table);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (ISNAN(x[i])) {
      continue;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (!ISNAN(y[j]) & x[i] == y[j]) {
        y[j] = NA_REAL;
        out[i] = j + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}')
```

Test

```
> cpmatch(control2, treat2)

  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43
 [38]  44  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  60  61  62  63  64  65  67  68  69  70  71  73  74  75  76  77  78  80  81  82  83  84  86  87  88
 [75]  89  90  91  93  94  95  96  97  99 100 101 102 103 104 106 107 108 109 110 112 113 114 115 116 117 119 120 121 122 123

> cpmatch(control1, treat1)

 [1]   1   2   3   4   5   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43
[38]  44  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  60  61  62  63  64  65  67  68  69  70  71  73  74  75  76  77  78  80  81  82  83  84  86  87  88
[75]  89  90  91  93  94  95  96  97  99 100 101 102 103 104 106 107 108 109 110 112 113 114 115 116 117
```

Benchmark

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(cpmatch(control1, treat1), pmatch(control1, treat1))

Unit: microseconds
                      expr   min    lq    mean median    uq   max neval cld
 cpmatch(control1, treat1)  16.9  17.3  19.795  17.55  18.1  55.7   100  a 
  pmatch(control1, treat1) 174.5 174.8 187.174 175.20 188.5 421.9   100   b
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a way to get the desired output from `pmatch`, but I have not been able to figure out how.  I tried looking at the `source code` for the `pmatch` function here:

```
R-4.0.3\src\library\base\R\match.R
```

But was not able to make progress that way.

So, I wrote the following `for-loop` to apply to the output of `pmatch` and replace the `NA's` with the `elements` I wanted.  It seems to work, at least for the example below.

```
my.vector <- c(1,  NA, NA, NA, NA,  8, NA, NA, NA, NA,
               NA, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21, NA, NA, NA,
               NA, NA, 27, NA, NA, NA, NA, 34, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

desired.result <- c(1,   2,  3,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,
                    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24,
                    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)

pos.not.na <- which(!is.na(my.vector))

if(any(is.na(my.vector)) == TRUE) {

     my.output <- my.vector

     for(i in 2:length(pos.not.na)) {

          my.output[pos.not.na[(i-1)]:(pos.not.na[i]-1)] <- seq(my.vector[pos.not.na[(i-1)]], 
          (my.vector[pos.not.na[(i-1)]] + (length(pos.not.na[(i-1)]:(pos.not.na[i]-1)) - 1)))

     }

     my.output[pos.not.na[length(pos.not.na)]:length(my.vector)] <- seq(my.vector[pos.not.na[length(pos.not.na)]],
          (my.vector[pos.not.na[length(pos.not.na)]] + length(pos.not.na[length(pos.not.na)]:length(my.vector)) - 1))

}

if(any(is.na(my.vector)) == FALSE) {my.output = my.vector}

my.output

all.equal(my.output, desired.result)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I don't think you should use `pmatch`. It converts your inputs into characters and finds the partial match for each element. For example, try this `pmatch(1, c(20,19))` and you will see it returns 2 because it finds `"1"` in `"19"`. @MarkMiller

Comment: @ekoam Thank you.  That is good to know.  Can you suggest a better way to obtain the desired example output in the original post?  I asked a similar question a few days ago: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086390/position-of-elements-from-one-vector-in-another-vector-with-r and someone suggested I use `pmatch`.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility might be to use `match` with `make.unique`. Also using `split` or using `Rcpp` will be possible.

```
pm <- function(x, y) {
    a <- split(seq_along(x), x)
    b <- split(seq_along(y), y)[names(a)]
    b[lengths(b)==0] <- NA
    b <- unlist(Map(`length<-`, b, lengths(a)), FALSE, FALSE)
    `[<-`(b, unlist(a, FALSE, FALSE), b) }

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=r"(
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector pmC(NumericVector a, NumericVector b) {
  IntegerVector idx(no_init(a.size()));
  std::unordered_map<float, std::queue<int> > lut;
  for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) lut[b[i]].push(i);
  for(int i = 0; i < idx.size(); ++i) {
    auto search = lut.find(a[i]);
    if(search != lut.end() && search->second.size() > 0) {
      idx[i] = search->second.front() + 1;
      search->second.pop();
    } else {idx[i] = NA_INTEGER;}
  }
  return idx;
}
)")
```

```
pm(control1, treat1)
pmC(control1, treat1)
match(make.unique(as.character(control1)), make.unique(as.character(treat1)))
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  21  22  23
#[20]  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44
#[39]  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  60  61  62  63  64  65  67  68
#[58]  69  70  71  73  74  75  76  77  78  80  81  82  83  84  86  87  88  89  90
#[77]  91  93  94  95  96  97  99 100 101 102 103 104 106 107 108 109 110 112 113
#[96] 114 115 116 117

pm(control2, treat2)
pmC(control2, treat2)
match(make.unique(as.character(control2)), make.unique(as.character(treat2)))
#  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  21  22
# [19]  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42
# [37]  43  44  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  60  61  62  63  64
# [55]  65  67  68  69  70  71  73  74  75  76  77  78  80  81  82  83  84  86
# [73]  87  88  89  90  91  93  94  95  96  97  99 100 101 102 103 104 106 107
# [91] 108 109 110 112 113 114 115 116 117 119 120 121 122 123
```

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(cpmatch = cpmatch(control1, treat1),
            pmatch = pmatch(control1, treat1),
            pm = pm(control1, treat1),
            pmC = pmC(control1, treat1),
            match = match(make.unique(as.character(control1)), make.unique(as.character(treat1)))
            )
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 cpmatch     14.08µs   14.7µs    56785.    4.28KB     5.68  9999     1
#2 pmatch     137.06µs  137.6µs     7085.    4.55KB     0     3542     0
#3 pm         256.02µs  263.2µs     3497.   15.84KB     8.27  1692     4
#4 pmC          9.76µs   10.6µs    93517.    2.93KB     9.35  9999     1
#5 match       180.6µs  181.5µs     5115.    9.89KB     0     2558     0
```